# jquery touchstart event not working in iphone

Tags: jquery

I am trying like this and its not working in iphone

```
$(document).bind('touchstart',function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

but its working like this

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
    alert('hello');
}, false);
```

how to get touchstart event working with jquery?

Its working with

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function(e){
            //e.preventDefault();
            var touch = e.touches[0] || e.changedTouches[0];
        });
```

but getting error e.touches is not an object

Comment: Have you tried: $(document).on('touchstart',function(){
    alert('hello');
});

?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the touches property you can use e.originalEvent:

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function(e){
  var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
});
```